# AngularJS: Menu Bar not working

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a web application from scratch. I have login form page which on successful authentication, navigates user to home page where we will have a menu bar and dashboard view. Now user can click on any menu option and navigates between pages.

My problem is i have to use ng-view in home.aspx and not in login.aspx. And all my scripts are included in login.aspx page. When I write routing in the home.aspx ng-view wont work. Can you please guide here?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your scripts to your layout page which is the parent of all pages when you add script over there it will be accessible to all application pages